# Deserializing Dynamic XML

Tags: c#, xml

In the first scenario, everything is pretty easy, I have the following XML, that I can deserialize to a strong type.

```
<providers>
   <dprovider>
      <dimensions>
         <width></width>
     </dimensions>
   </dbrovider>
```

In the 2nd scenario, and this is where I need help... I have something a little more dynamic

```
<providers>
   <dprovider>
      <dimensions>
         <width></width>
     </dimensions>
   </dbrovider>
     <dprovider>
      <dimensions>
         <height></height>
     </dimensions>
   </dbrovider>
```

As you can see the dimensions sub structure is different in both items, so I need to find a way to create the strongly typed class, so that it can handle any change to the dimensions element, it could for example contain a whole nested sub structure, different for each dbprovider.

Any ideas on how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Serializable]
class Dimension { ... }

[Serializable]
class Height : Dimension { ... }

[Serializable]
class Width : Dimension { ... }
```

Then, in the class that your  (note the plural) element deserializes into, have this property:

```
[XmlElement( Type = typeof( Height ), ElementName = "height" )]
[XmlElement( Type = typeof( Width ), ElementName = "width" )]
public Dimension[] DimensionArray {
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

Here's the starting point of [documentation on XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) (XmlElement class), so you can figure out the rest of the details.

You should be able to serialize/deserialize your providers object by simply decorating the right properties and classes with the right attributes from the **System.Xml.Serialization** namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing the point of C# to XML Serialization/Deserialization.

You should either define a schema (or use the one you already have) and create a C# class that supports it.  [See MSDN article on xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)

The other route is to create your C# class (and wrap it in a collection from your markup) and add XML attributes.  This will essentially define your XML schema.  [See here for starting point on the XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx)

Comment: You may want to use the DataContractSerializer which can handle collections better then the normal xml serializer. I cannot tell though if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps to mind is custom deserialization.  At that point, your dprovider class can have a List<object> called Dimensions, which has the host of subjobjects you require.  The only pain is pulling them back out, because you'll have to do a bunch of "is" logic.

If you're looking to have a "whole nested sub structure", that sub structure should be defined as its own class/struct, then added to the Dimensions list.

Comment: if I have list of object, then -> I guess I can hold any object, with any structure in that collection?

Comment: Exactly, but I'm not sure if this is filling your "needs to be strongly typed" requirement, since your code will look like:

if (dProvider.Dimensions[0] is ObjWithHeight)
  height = ((ObjWithHeight)dProvider.Dimensions[0]).Height;

Having to do that casting every time is a royal pain.  If you were to provide more clarification on what you're end goal is (rather than the method you chose), there might be a different method the community could suggest than custom deserialization + Object list + casting.